# linq looping through tags with the same name

Tags: c#, linq

I'm some what new to linq could uses some help..

I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
  <InputPath>
      <path isRename="Off" isRouter="Off" pattern="pattern-1">d:\temp1</path>
      <path isRename="Off" isRouter="pattern-1">d:\temp2</path>
  </InputPath>
```

I need to loop through and get the  key values of the tag "path".

What I have so far is

```
var results = from c in rootElement.Descendants("InputPath") select c;

foreach (XElement _path in results)
{
    string value = _path.Element("path").Value;
}
```

But I only get the last `<path>` value. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll only get the *first* element that way, because that's what the [`Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) method gives you: the first child element with the given name.

If you want multiple elements you can just use [`Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements.aspx) instead:

```
// Note: the query expression here is pointless.
var results = from c in rootElement.Descendants("InputPath") select c;
foreach (XElement _path in results)
{
    string value = _path.Elements("path").Value;
    // Use value here...        
}
```

Alternatively, use the [`Elements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351784.aspx) extension method and do it all in one go:

```
foreach (var path in rootElement.Descendants("InputPath").Elements("path"))
{
    string value = path.Value;
    // Use value here  
}
```

If that doesn't help, please give more information about what you're trying to do and what the problem is.

If by "last" you mean "the element contents" that's because you're using the `Value` property. If you want the *attributes* within the path element, you need the [`Attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute.aspx) method, as shown by IamStalker, although personally I'd usually cast the `XAttribute` to string (or whatever) rather than using the `Value` property, in case the attribute is missing. (It depends on what you want the behaviour to be in that case.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just just enumerating the path items?

```
foreach (var element in rootElement.Descendants("path"))
{
    var value = element.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is, to loop through the attributes like so

```
foreach (XElement xElem in rootElement.Descendants("InputPath"))
{
    string isRename = xElem.Attribute("isRename").Value;

}
```